# postgresql join on json array that inclues a given value

Tags: sql, postgresql

given 2 tables: one named `foo` with a column named `vals` that holds a jsonb array, e.g. `[ "val-1", "val-2", ..., "val-n" ]`; and a second table named `baz` with a column named `val` that holds a string, e.g. `val-k`.

how can the tables be joined, such that `baz.val` is included in `foo.vals`?

i have tried the following, but clearly it does not work.

```sql
select *
from baz
join foo
on foo.vals @> baz.val;
```

Comment: When reporting an error, you should actually report it.  "Does not work" is not a description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have arrays like yours you need to use other operator.
Can you try:

```
select * 
from baz
join foo
on foo.vals ? baz.val
```

as example you can run first

```
    select '[ "val-1", "val-2","val-n" ]'::jsonb ? 'val-2'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an other why to do it using text comparison `LIKE` :

```
select *
from baz
join foo
on foo.vals::varchar like '%"' || baz.val || '"%';
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZqnR9aeP)